# N loop string then move to the end

Tags: c

N loop to clone first string then move to the end of array

```
name = ["A" , "B", "C"]
```

Comment: Given the code in the question and the accepted answer, why is this tagged [c]?  Looking at the edit history, you appear to have vandalised your own question to the point it no longer makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elegant way to do the job by writting a recursive function:

```
def f(N, n, result):
    if n == 0:
        return result[-1]
    else:
        return f(N, n - 1, result[1:] + [result[0]] * N)

def g(N, n, result):
    for _ in range(n):
        result = result[1:] + list(result[0]) * N
    return result[-1]

N = 2
print("N: " + str(N))
for n in range(1, 3):
    result = "".join(f(N, n, ["A" , "B", "C"]))
    last = result[-1]
    print("_" * 5)
    print("n: " + str(n))
    print("Result: " + str(result))
    print("Last: " + str(last))
```

Here the result:

```
N: 2
_____
n: 1
Result: BCAA
Last: A
_____
n: 2
Result: CAABB
Last: B
```

This method (f) is way slower than the other answer (g) and you are limited by recursion depth of python if n is over 997 on my computer. You can change it using `sys.setrecursionlimit(xxx)`

Time comparaison:

- f: for n from 1 to 997: `2.130194664001465 s`
- g: for n from 1 to 997: `1.02400803565979 s`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
def my_func() :
    name = ["A" , "B", "C"]
    value = input("Number of n : ")
    value = int(value)
    for n in range(0, value):
        name = name[1:] + list(name[0]) * 2
        print(name)
    return name[-1]


print(my_func())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Number of n : 2
['B', 'C', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
B
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe help you!

```
name = ["A" , "B", "C"]
def my_func() :
    value = input("Number of n : ")
    value = int(value)
    for i in range(value):
        # get first element then remove
        first_element = name.pop(0)
        # move to then end list name
        name.extend([first_element,first_element])
        # print current list name
        print(name)
    #print last name
    print(name[-1])
```

Test case:

```
Number of n : 2
['B', 'C', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
B

Number of n : 3
['B', 'C', 'A', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
C
```